# More tables or more columns (in my simple example)?

Tags: database-design

I'm modelling DB and wondering if I should create more very simple tables or just have more columns in tables.

I mean, let's assume I have s table named `User`, each user can have status(ACTIVE, INACTIVE, BLOCKED, ...). Should I store status directly in `User`(as an `ENUM`?) table or maybe it's better to create a table named `UserStatus` with status ID, status name and FK pointing to the user?

Similar with employees and their position(manager, developer, etc.).

Can you give me some advices?

Answer (score 1):

Typically user would have the fk

user:
ID (pk)
Name
StatusID (fk referencing status.ID)

status:
ID (pk)
Name

A user has a status - not a status has a user

Answer (score 1):

On relations which are one to one (one User has one Status) it often is better to add a column to your table. If it is more complex or you want to make your Software prepared for future requests, make a table. For example could it be possible that one employee could have several positions. This would be a one to multiple relation. In this case you would store that data in an extra table. There is not a wrong or right. You always have to check your needs.